# how to send http request to server via android app

Tags: android, networking, android-networking

I run my script in catalyst server. So i have requirement of make request from android mobile to my server.i use this code but it give (java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=intent} to activity) error message.

Any one know what is the problem help me

thank you

```
try
{   
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost = new HttpPost("http://myipandport");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("barcode", "hai"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
}


catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/examples.html  choose a sample, open up Internet permission in the manifest.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> I add this code in my manifest

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code you posted is not related to the error message you mentioned.

The error message describes that something went wrong on handling "onActivityResult" so that you should check your activity implementation that overrides "onActivityResult", or check your activity that sends result intent.

Comment: Thank you for reply.You mean to say there is no error in sending request to server. Error in activity. But when in comment this code my application run with out any error.